# Graph API-OneDrive Unable to set linked based permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using Graph API I want to set permissions for an OneDrive item. The type of permission I want to set is "Specific People" under "Link Settings". But I am unable to do so.

I have tried following with createLink option.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01BTTSDZ432FOIS2PPQJD3N6QYQ4V2DEXS/createlink

Request Body:
{
"type": "edit",
"scope": "users"
}

But I get response saying:
"code": "invalidRequest",
"message": "Scope must be either 'organization' or 'anonymous'.",

So it looks like "scope": "users" is not allowed in createlink. But that seems to be the right option for "Specific People" permissions.

Also, I am unable to figure out a way to specify a specific user (whom I want to give rights) in the above request.

Let me know if anyone has faced similar issue and if there is any way to set such permissions using Graph API.

Comment: I don't think you can create link for specific people as it supports the [scope value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#scope-types) as 'organization' or 'anonymous'. Try to use [invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite) as it has recipients property where you can specify specific users.

Comment: Yes. Tried using invite but it doesn't create Link Based permissions. It creates Direct Access permission and I don't want that.

Comment: I have a feeling I read that the "users" scope is only usable on Sharepoint drives, not OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should first create a company sharable link with type `view`.

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink

{
  "type": "view",
  "scope": "organization"
}
```

Use the link's `webUrl` from the response and grant specific users access to the link and specify roles to be granted to the users.

```
POST /shares/{encoded-sharing-url}/permission/grant

{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "john@contoso.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "ryan@external.com"
    }
  ],
  "roles": ["write"]
}
```

[Grant access to sharing link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: But it will give read only access to anyone in the organization with the link. Not something I want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to allow external guests to read/view the file. the beta endpoint has

POST /sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}/createLink

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

which creates links for specific people using the scope - "users"

drive level links are organisational wide but aren't for external users, which have been invited into the tenant.

see notes:

Specific people creates a link that only the people that you specify can use to access the file, folder, or list item. If you select this option, enter the names or email addresses of the people to whom you want to give access to the file, folder, or list item. Use this to share with people inside or outside your organization but when you want to make sure it doesn't work if they forward it on to others.

https://support.office.com/client/results?ns=SPOSTANDARD&version=16&helpid=WSSEndUser_ODSPSharingOptions_FL846149&app=webview

the docs are good if u want a specific level invite/permissions/scopes but not so good when you want something more complex.